# Oracle forms firing for update of nowait query in background after migration to 12c

Tags: oracle, oracleforms, select-for-update

After migration to oracle 12c db and forms on a particular form in query mode we are unable to type anything and in the trace log I can see select..for update of column_name nowait query is getting fired automatically whenever trying to type anything in any of fields.

Comment: Does the for update statement gives an error ?

Comment: No. It executes perfectly fine if we run it from sql plus.

Comment: No I mean, it tries to lock the record, so it can be that the locking gives an error.
When the locking gives an error you won't be able to input something

Comment: There are no errors in Form trace  files. When I execute this select statement from sql plus it executes and gives no locking issue as such

Comment: Just noticed few things when I am running this query on 11g it says that resource is busy which means object is already locked and hence no further lock can be obtained on the same object. While when I execute this query on 12c env, query executes successfully i.e. it is able to obtain lock from sql developer which means that lock obtained through forms was unsuccessful although in locked object I can see table in both the environments.

Comment: We're not on 12c Forms yet, so I have no way of checking this at the moment, but could it have something to do with either the form-level Interaction Mode property, or the block-level Locking Mode or Key Mode property?

Comment: I have checked all the above properties and changing it makes no difference. But a point worth noting is that when I compare the properties on block level on similar form which is working fine then get a difference between Insert allowed and Update allowed properties but when I go to individual form and click on block properties, then properties of both blocks are same.

Comment: Andy, issue is resolved once I changed block level property Locking mode from Automatic to Delayed. Do you know what this property value means. I have also raised this with Oracle support. Thanks a lot for your help, really helpful.